# C# - How to make (Exception ex) as public

Tags: c#

How can I make ex accessible after a try catch block?
Like this...

```
try
{
    // do something...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // skip here...
}
//execute **ex** here
```

Why do I want to do this?
If I write:

```
try
{
    // do something...
    // i already declared x as public.
    x = "what ever";
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // if there's an error...
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
// Even there's an error,
// there's still no output.
```

So maybe if ex is public, I can try this:

```
try
{
    // do something...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // skip here...
}
// execute **ex** here
```

Comment: declare x before try-catch scope

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve? This is quite a bizarre programming pattern.

Comment: Nothing works
But I got this
when try catch block encountered an error,
It exits the thread.
That's why there's no output.
I'll try to find another solution.
And will ask if there's another problem

By the way, thanks to all your answers.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you mean with "execute ex", but this is how you could access the Exception after the `catch` block:

```
Exception ex = null;
try
{
    // do something...
}
catch (Exception ex1) {
    ex = ex1;
}

if(ex != null)
   // ...
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Exception exceptionObject = null;

try
{
    // do something...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    exceptionObject = ex;
}
// execute **ex** here
if(exceptionObject != null)
{
    //do a thing
}
```

The thing you are doing is weird. Stop it.

Comment: +1 for the notice of weird and the recommendation to stop it.